# How do I find the Google billing account/project related to an API key?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

we look after some websites built by other people and have had issues with the map not working because the associated billing account is invalid, but we have no idea what account or project name it relates to! Is there a way to look up the API key and get back to the account? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that information is public, otherwise anyone could just get that information from any website with google maps

Comment: Create a new key in an account you control and use it to replace the one on the page(s) you are having the issue with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the screen and navigate to inspect element. You will get the code written, find out the api key written in the code. Go to your google api console find out the project which is attached to your api key.
Hope it Helps!
Thanks!